# In Java, how do you hide a JList after making a selection?

Tags: java, swing, hide, jlist

I'm making a simple rock, paper scissor game in Java, and I have two JLists where Player 1 and Player 2 can make their selection. The thing is, I want the JList to be hidden when a selection is made (for obvious reasons, otherwise there'd be no point with the game ^_^), but I havent found a way to do this and still keep the selected value. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like it hidden from view or disabled from interaction with the user?

Comment: Is your goal to hide it from the user, or to remove it from the enclosing panel?

Comment: The goal is to hide it from the user, so that when player 1 selects e.g  rock, that list will be hidden when player 2 makes his selection on another JList.

Comment: You could use a `JComboBox` or `JDialog` instead??

Comment: My choice: use two computers connected over a network. Only display on one computer that which should only be seen by that user.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels maybe it's over-complicated to do this with two computers. I think he can use something with modal dialog box like:
RED TURN. Blue, give the mouse to him. OK
RED, make your selection OK
BLUE TURN. Red, five the mouse to blue. OK
BLUE, make your selection OK

and then check the win... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JList extends JComponent, which has an [extensive list of methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) you could use to varying degrees.  For example, if you just want to disable the JList from user interaction, there is [setEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) which will "grey" out that component.  If you want to hide the JList completely, see [setVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

Whichever route you take, just drop one of these methods in where your user makes their selection, and you should be good to go.  In order to store the user's selection, you'll want to save that to a variable that goes beyond that particular JList so you can later compare it with the opponent's value.  I'd recommend giving [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) a read.

Answer (score 0):

jlist1.setVisible(false) will make it invisible